# Compile angular code directly in the browser

Tags: angular, compilation, ng-build

I need to compile the angular code directly in the browser so that the output will be same as the output that we get after we do **ng-build** in the local system.

So basically I need to perform ng-build(or something similar) in the browser itself. After the execution, I can use the compiled code for other purposes.

I will get the code like this,

```
{
[relative path to file]: the actual code
}
```

eg:

```
{
"/src/app/app.component.html": "<div>Hello World</div>",
....
}
```

I tried sandpack, but could not achieve this.

Comment: Are you talking about an online code editor? if yes, then you can give a try https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: Yes I am talking about an online code editor. But I need it to be embedded the editor inside my application.